# Issue with "blocky" model in x3dom

Tags: 3d, x3d, x3dom

I am trying to use a 3d Studio Max model with x3dom. I did not create the model nor do I know much about 3d rendering/animation. The image on the left shows the rending of the model from 3d Studio Max. The image on the right shows the same model inside of x3dom.

[link to image](http://www.masterkeyhost.com/skull_test.jpg)

I started off with a .3ds, a .max, and a .wrl file. I converted all three of these to .x3d. Each one gave the same results.

I am new to x3dom, but it seems pretty straightforward as far as displaying pre-made models. Is there some settings that I need to implement to get the x3dom to look as smooth as the original model? I have looked at other samples on the x3dom web site and they seem to all render properly/smoothly.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that mesh does not contain [normal vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_%28geometry%29) and you have to say x3dom to calculate them. Check [Online normal creation](http://x3dom.org/x3dom/example/x3dom_creaseAngle.html), that might help..

Answer (score 0):

You should also check the `creaseAngle` of the geometries: something like **3.14** would be good whereas the default **0** would render blocky like on your screenshot.

Comment: This is also correct, I marked Sorceror's as the correct answer since his page link offered more detailed info and some examples.